# Tensorflow GPU build with CPU

Tags: tensorflow

Does the tensorflow GPU version can be used with CPU only machines?
Getting some issues with Tensorflow 1.5 regarding cuda libraries not found.

Anybody tried this?

Answer (score 2):

The CUDA 9 library is required for tensorflow-gpu version 1.5 and above, and CUDA 9 must be installed with a CUDA-capable GPU. You should probably install the CPU version of Tensorflow.